# Reading instance variables using self

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-variables

I know that within class instance I should read variables' values via instance variables.
But what are the consequences of reading them via self?

See example below:

```
class Test   attr_writer :aa
  def testing
    puts @aa
    puts self.aa <-- what are the consequences if I apply attr_reader :aa and try to read 'aa' via self.aa ? can I read other value by accident?
  end

  def self.bb
    a = self.new
    a.aa = "111"
    a.testing
  end
end

Test.bb
```

Comment: `puts self.aa` is the same as `puts aa`.  That's because `self` is the default receiver.  Since `testing` is an instance method, it is called by an instance of `Test`, so `self` equals that instance within the method.  You can confirm that by adding `puts "self = #{self}"` within the method.  The effect of `puts aa` (or `puts self.aa`) depends on whether you have created an accessor for `aa` (e.g., `attr_reader :aa`).  If you have, `puts aa` will give the value of @aa via the accessor; if you haven't, an exception will be raised, informing you that there is no local variable or method `aa`.

Comment: Ok, any particular reason for the : "But using the method instead of @variable is recommended for various reasons." ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example the variable is an instance variable to the object you just created with the `self.new`

Also is important to know that within the `testing` method self references to the object and not the class as It seems you think to. And within the `bob` method, since it's a class method, self references to the class.

Still, you can have instance variables within the class itself (not to be confused with class variables @@ that are accessible within all the class objects and the class itself).

Here is an example of what it can look like.

```
class Test

  class << self
    attr_writer :bb
  end

  def self.bb
    @bb
  end
end

Test.bb = 1
Test.bb
```

Comment: Thank you I have edited my post and changed 'class' to 'instance'

Comment: Ok I understand what you wrote, and I understand the differences, but I am just wondering what might go wrong if I try to read the variable using self.aa instead of @aa in the testing method

Comment: If you use attr_reader :aa is the same of having a method like `def aa; @aa; end` so it's almost the same. But using the method instead of @variable is recommended for various reasons.